# Webpack-dev-server sub pages not found

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, webpack-dev-server, file-not-found

I'm using react with webpack. My app worked well before using webpack-dev-server. Only the home page works now, the others return "404 not found". Maybe there's a problem in webpack.config.js ?

```
var webpack = require("webpack");
var path = require("path");

var BUILD_DIR = path.resolve(__dirname, "public");
var APP_DIR = path.resolve(__dirname, "app");

var config = {
    entry: [
        "webpack/hot/only-dev-server",
        APP_DIR + "/main.js",
        "webpack-dev-server/client?localhost:8080"
    ],

    output: {
        path: BUILD_DIR + "/dist",
        filename: "bundle.js",
    },

    plugins: [
        new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
            $: "jquery",
            jQuery: "jquery"
        }),
        new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin()
    ],

    module: {
        loaders: [...],
    },

    devServer: {
        noInfo: true,
        hot: true,
        inline: true
    },
}

module.exports = config;
```

And my script in package.json:

```
"start": "webpack --watch & webpack-dev-server --content-base public"
```

Webpack generates well bundle file. So i think the webpack-dev-server is the one who causes this problem.

Thank you !

Comment: Are they regular html files? I believe webpack dev server flattens everything into one directory and doesn't preserve source directory structure by default.

Comment: I used react, sorry for not mention that.  So i have index.html and bundle.js in folder "puclic"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've found the answer. For someone who has the same problem, we need to add "historyApiFallback: true" to devServerConfig:

```
devServer: {
    noInfo: true,
    hot: true,
    inline: true,
    historyApiFallback: true
},
```

Answer (score 0):

can you change your npm script

```
"start": "webpack --watch & webpack-dev-server --content-base public"
```

to

```
"start": "webpack --watch & webpack-dev-server --content-base public/"
```

and see what happens? Otherwise I will comeback and assist you.

Comment: Sorry but nothing happens. I've changed "public" to "public/". Thanks

Comment: Can you give me more context? Are you using react router? When does that 404 page happen?

For example, if you have  example.com/test   URL. Does 404 happen when you enter example.com/test directly into the URL bar?

Comment: Yes, i used react-router. "localhost:8080" gives me the home page, but "localhost:8080/login" returns 404 with the message "Cannot GET /login". I tried to click a link or type directly into the URL bar but it's always the same.

Comment: And i'm pretty sure that there is not problem with my code because before using webpack, everything worked well.

Comment: I think webpack-dev-server not support browserHistory maybe

Comment: I found how to resolve this problem. I just need to add "historyApiFallback: true" into webpack devServer config. Thank you anyway